# 'The remote name could not be resolved' using IIS, but IIS Express works

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-express

I´m developing a C# Web-Application, which uses a webservice for getting data.

I get following error: "**The remote name could not be resolved**".

The strange thing is that it **works with IIS Express**, **but not** with IIS.

Edit:
my WebConfig:

```
    <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransactionalWebServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="64000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://XXXXXX:443/XXXX"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWebServiceBinding"
    contract="reference_XXXX.work_order_managementPortType" name="TransactionalWebServicePort" />
</client>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are they running on the same server? Can you ping the remote host from the IIS server?

Comment: During developing I used an IIS-Express server. Now I want to move the complete application from the IIS-Express-Server to an IIS Environment. 
Both, the IIS-Express and IIS, are on the same machine.

Comment: Is the address for the web service in the `web.config` file?

Comment: Do you use a proxy? Maybe IIS Express goes through proxy because it runs under your account (I'm just guessing).